# Android Developer Console: Delete App

Tags: android, google-play

I am thinking of deleting my unpublished app. in the developer console.

Then, create a new app. and refill all the information and settings.

The Question: Can I use the same app name I used in the deleted app?

Comment: Can you tell me, How do you deleted app?

Comment: I didn't proceed with the action. My client changed his mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. I've done this before. You will have to use a different bundle name though. For example if your bundle name was com.apolloss.BowlingGame, you have to name it something different.